# How to get php $_POST['VARIABLE'] where input name is also a variable

Tags: javascript, php, mysqli

I have a form with JS like

```
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = '<input type="hidden" name="qc" value='+qs+'>';
for(count=1; count<=qs; count++)
                    {
                    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML  += '<br><font style="font-size: 20px">'+ count+'. <input class="textboxtest" style="width:850px;" type="text" name=" q'+ count +' " placeholder="Question "><br>' ;
```

}
I want to insert the textbox value in database with mysqli and PHP.

My PHP code is

```
$count = $_POST['qc'];
        for($i= 1; $i <= $count ; $i++) 
            {
                $ques ="q".$i;
                $qs = $_POST[$ques]; 
                mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO ques ('".$qs."') VALUES ('".$qs."')");
            }
```

I am getting error like  Undefined index: q1 .
 Undefined index: q2  and so on as the value of the count increase.

My question is how to insert textbox value into database with that textbox name which is a variable.

Comment: `foreach ($_POST as $key => $val) {}`

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the $ques index is setted before running the query:

```
$count = $_POST['qc'];
        for($i= 1; $i <= $count ; $i++) 
            {
                $ques ="q".$i;
                if (isset($_POST[$ques])){
                    $qs = $_POST[$ques]; 
                    mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO ques ('".$qs."') VALUES ('".$qs."')");
                }
            }
```

Comment: data are not getting into database table

Comment: Is $_POST['qc'] setted? 
If is setted, it means that no one of your "qXX" is setted...